# In Backbone.js using jQuery, what is the correct way to select an element within a view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In the code below I have two jQuery selectors that seem to work correctly.  Is there a reason to do one instead of the other, or is there another preferred way?

```
var val1 = $("#username", this.el ).val()
var val2 = $(this.el).find("#username").val();
```

I'm aware that there should not be multiple elements with the same id, but if there are multiple elements with the same id, what is the best way to select only the element in the view (see example below for username).

```
<body>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" /><br />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="login">
        Username: <input type="text" id="username" /><br />
        <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: "#login",
            events: {
                "click #loginButton": "login"
            },

            login: function () {
                var val1 = $("#username", this.el ).val()
                var val2 = $(this.el).find("#username").val();

                console.log(val1);
                console.log(val2);
            }
        })
        var loginView = new LoginView();
    </script>    
</body>
```

--------------------- Update ------------------------

I create jsFiddle example so that there could be a working example for other to look at.
http://jsfiddle.net/BarDev/9QpKy/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For brevity, I usually use the [Backbone-provided shortcut](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar):

```
this.$('#username')
```

which is an alias for `$('#username', this.el);`

However, any selection method you use will work well enough. The other two ways that you've got in your example are good.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would suggest you not to have multiple elements with same id on a page. Try to avoid that. Coming to find an element, I think `find` is better than selecting element passing the context because context is good for performance reason but `find` is faster than `context` so it is better and also it is more compact and readable.

```
var val2 = $(this.el).find("#username").val();
```

Comment: I havn't check but I think that when selecting by id the context is not so important performance wise. But it's still a good advice in other cases

Comment: @Guillaume86 - Yes, if the ids are unique then there is not need to pass the context of find with in a jQuery object, you can directly use the id selector.